# What does the O(1) in "ln ln n / ln 2 + O(1)" mean?

Tags: math, big-o, theory

I have difficulty understand the O(1) notation in this formula, does it stand for a constant? Why would people use big-O notation like this?

[image: formula]

This formula comes from the paper ["Balanced Allocations" by Azar et al.](http://users.eecs.northwestern.edu/~nickle/randAlg/AzarBKU99.pdf), and this formulas is used in the abstract:

[image: abstract]

Comment: It's hard to say without context.

Comment: This is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697918/what-does-o1-access-time-mean

Comment: @dexterous No, it's not. The question isn't about what big-O means

Comment: @icepack It's not the most _helpful_ answer, but that's actually exactly what the question is. Isn't OP just confused about what the definition of Big-Oh notation is? That SO post answers it. If he did understand the definition then there would be no question here.

Comment: @roliu- I don't think the OP is confused about the definition of big-O notation as applied to algorithms as much as the use of the terminology "f(n) + O(n)," which is not commonly encountered in basic algorithmic analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Here, the term O(1) means "some term that is O(1)," meaning some term that as n goes to infinity is bounded from above by some constant.  For example, it might be 137, or sin n, or 1 / n<sup>2</sup>.  The value described therefore might be ln ln n / ln 2 + 137, or ln ln n / ln 2 + sin n, etc.

This use of big-O notation is common in formal mathematics when discussing low order terms in a formula that contribute a small amount to the overall total.  The authors could have also written that the entire expression is O(ln ln n), but this is less precise than ln ln n / ln 2 + O(1) because it obscures the fact that the coefficient on the ln ln n is 1 / ln 2 and that the only low-order growth term is bounded from above by a constant.  By explicitly writing out " + O(1)", the authors are able to give much better precision.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `O(1)` means constant. The exact value of the constant isn't specified but it's probably not important for the given expression. Such notions are normally used as an intermediate step in a calculation and it removes calculation of unimportant details.

Read this expression as follows: the execution takes `lnlnn/ln2` time with some constant addition. Summing this up results in `O(lnlnn)`. Replacing `O(1)` with exact expression wouldn't change this result so it's ok to use approximation in the form of `O(1)`.

Comment: I updated my question. In fact, it is not about the execution time of a program, but an upper bound of the number of balls in a bin. So the O(1) matters a lot, and I don't know how to under stand.

Comment: O(1) does not mean "constant."  It means "something bounded from above by a constant as n goes to infinity."

Comment: @Bloodmoon You haven't specified it so I assumed you're talking about time. But it doesn't change the concept - in your case the resource is number of balls instead of time

Comment: @templatetypedef Formally speaking, correct. But there is no contradiction - O(1) is replaceable with that bounding constant - if we're talking in terms of big-O the result will be the same. Hope my answer is clearer now