# Performance Difference For-Loop Foreach

Tags: java

I always asked myself "what to use" should I use a for-loop or a foreach.
In my opinion it's both the "same". I know for iterating through a list etc. is a foreach better but what if we have the following case :

```
for (String zipCode : zipCodes) {
    if (zipCode.equals(zip)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < zipCodes.length; i++) {
    if (zipCodes[i].equals(zip)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What would be better? Or is in this case really no difference?

Comment: which is more readable?

Comment: As for performance - try it yourself

Comment: Also, in this specific case, `zipCodes.contains(zip)` would be best.

Comment: I have to say it's an array i truly can convert it to a list but this would be inefficient.  More readable is the first case, in my opinion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first - `for-each` is nothing but syntactic sugar for `Iterator`. Read [this section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) of JLS. So, I will address this question as a simple FOR loop vs Iterator.

Now, when you use `Iterator` to traverse over a collection, at bare minimum you will be using two method - `next()` and `hasNext()`, and below are their `ArrayList` implementations:

```
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = I]; // hagrawal: this is what simple FOR loop does
    }
```

Now, we all know the basic computing that there will be performance difference if on the processor I have to just execute `myArray[i]` v/s complete implementation of `next()` method. So, there has to be a difference in performance.

It is likely that some folk might come back strongly on this, citing performance benchmarks and excerpts from Effective Java, but the only other way I can try to explain is that this is even written in Oracle's official documentation - please read below from `RandomAccess` interface docs over [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html).

[image]

It is very clearly mentioned that there will be differences. So, if you can convince me that what is written in official docs is wrong and will be changed, I will be ready to accept the argument that there is no performance difference between simple FOR loop and Iterator or for-each.

**So IMHO, correct way to put this whole argument is this:**

1. If the collection implements `RandomAccess` interface then simple FOR loop will perform (at least theoretically) better than Iterator or for-each. (this is what is also written in [RandomAccess docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html))
2. If the collection doesn't implement `RandomAccess` interface then Iterator or for-each will perform (for sure) better than simple FOR loop.
3. However, for all practical purposes, for-each is the best choice in general.

Answer (score 3):

If `zipCodes[i]` is not O(1), then the performance of your second case will be much worse. (That said, I don't think there *yet* exists a container in Java where `[]` is *not* O(1)). Put another way, the short form `for` loop *cannot* be slower.

Plus the short form `for` loop is clearer, which really ought to be the primary consideration unless speed *matters*.

Comment: Just to clarify for those who don't know: `O(1)` means the algorithm is not dependent on the number of elements. This is as opposed to `O(n)`, in which the algorithm takes proportionally longer the more elements are added. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697918/what-does-o1-access-time-mean

Answer (score 3):

It is less about optimisation nowadays, as any difference will be unnoticeable, unless you need to process a very large amount of data. Also, if you used a Collection, the performance would depend on the chosen implementation.

What you should really think about is the quality of the code. The rule is that you should **use as few elements as possible to present the logic as clearly as possible**. The second solution introduces a new element, the i index, which is not actually needed and only makes the code this little bit more complicated. Only use the fori loop if you actually need to know the index in each iteration.

So, from code quality perspective, you should use the first solution :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Note that there is no performance penalty for using the for-each loop,
>   even for arrays. In fact, it may offer a slight performance advantage
>   over an ordinary for loop in some circumstances, as it computes the
>   limit of the array index only once.

Item 46 in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Comment: `computes the limit of the array index only once.` That's outdated, all counted loops receive JIT optimization and loops bounded by array size have index checking removed as a matter of routine.