# How can I compare two array value and return what i want value?

Tags: php

Existing Record:

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987860"
    "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987893"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987862"
    "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987894"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [
    "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987861"
    "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987895"
  ]
]
```

GroupTaskUuid Array:

```
array:2 [
  0 => "98790287437987862"
  1 => "98790287437987861"
]
```

How can I compare two arrays with the "groupTaskUuid" but return "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" value in the result?

Result what I want (that is "purchaseOrderGroupTasks"):

```
array:2 [
    "0" => "98790287437987894"
    "1" => "98790287437987895"
]
```

Comment: If you are not hunting for speed, then loop through first one and do an in_array() check.

Comment: Do you have any attempt of yours to show?

Comment: it would be a lot of record in reality @vivek_23

Comment: Any update....?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
$filtered = array_filter(
                $records, 
                function($el) use($GroupTaskUuid) { 
                    return in_array($el["groupTaskUuid"], $GroupTaskUuid); 
                }
             );

$only_purchase_column = array_column($filtered, "purchaseOrderGroupTasks")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said there would be a lot of rows, you will need to convert `GroupTaskUuid` array to an associative array where those UUIDs are keys. This way you can do an [`isset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) check in [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697918/what-does-o1-access-time-mean) time on average.

You loop through the dataset, check if that UUID key exists in our map and if it exists, collect it's `purchaseOrderGroupTasks` in a new result array.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$data = [
      [
        "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987860",
        "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987893"
      ],
      [
        "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987862",
        "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987894"
      ],
      [
        "groupTaskUuid" => "98790287437987861",
        "purchaseOrderGroupTasks" => "98790287437987895"
      ]
];

$GroupTaskUuid = [
       "98790287437987862",
       "98790287437987861"
    ];

$GroupTaskUuidFlipped = array_flip($GroupTaskUuid); // make UUID values as keys
$purchaseOrderGroupTasks = [];

foreach($data as $value){
    if(isset($GroupTaskUuidFlipped[$value['groupTaskUuid']])){
        $purchaseOrderGroupTasks[] = $value['purchaseOrderGroupTasks'];
    }
}

print_r($purchaseOrderGroupTasks);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$purchaseOrderGroupTasks = [];
foreach($GroupTaskUuid as $uuid){
    if($key = array_search($uuid, array_column($data, 'groupTaskUuid')) !== false)
        $purchaseOrderGroupTasks[] = $data[$key]['key'];
}
```