# ruby loop refactor

Tags: ruby, arrays, refactoring

I have a loop that looks like this

```
def slow_loop(array)
 array.each_with_index do |item, i|
   next_item = array[i+1]
   if next_item && item.attribute == next_item.attribute
     do_something_with(next_item)
   end
 end
end
```

aside from changing the way do_something_with is called, how can i make this perform better?

thx,

-C

p.s.

Since it appears that this is an 'O(n)' operation, there is apparently no performance to be gained here, so the answer i chose is one that uses a ruby method that already encapsulates this operation. thanks for your help everybody

Comment: Perhaps you should let us know how many elements you have and any sort of benchmarking figures you came up with?   This SHOULD be a O(n) operation.

Comment: forgive me if this sounds dumb, but, what's an O(n) operation?

Comment: Basically, the time of the operation O is a directly related to the number of elements n

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133008/what-is-big-o-notation-do-you-use-it (and more links in the question).

Comment: It's worth noting that just because it's an O(n) algorithm doesn't mean that you *can't* get any more performance out of it.

There are lots of times when the best possible algorithm is O(n) but you can still shoot yourself in the foot with a pathological O(n) algorithm.  e.g., iterating over a matrix column-major when it's stored row-major.

In your case, it's a really simple algorithm, and not much room for improvement.  But keep in mind that even though you should examine the complexity of your algorithm *first*, getting the best performance is often about large constant factors.

Comment: O(n) just defines how the function's execution time scales with the size of the dataset it's operating on. Something that takes five years per element is still O(n).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned you're not going to improve the performance much, but you could do this more cleanly like so:

```
array.each_cons(2) do |a, b|
  do_something_with(b) if a == b
end
```

Comment: should next_item be 'b' here?

Comment: Interesting - I hadn't seen each_cons before.

Comment: @Sara Mei: It's in enumerable... there is also each_slice, which is the non-sliding window version.

Comment: although it sucks my performance loss is not coming from the loop, this is a pretty nice way of doing this.. thx :)

Comment: Note that each_cons and each_slice are only in native Ruby as of 1.9, although they do exist in the Enumerable extensions implemented in Rails from (at least, possibly earlier) 2.1.2 onwards

Answer (score 2):

The performance of `do_something_with` is the main factor. Anything else would be micro-optimisation.

This should be O(n), you could work out a way to avoid the final check, but that's not going to be that costly in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: if that's the case, I guess my only other question would be, is there a ruby method that already encapsulates this type of procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree with Garry on the optimization potential, but it can certainly be written more simply.

```
prev_attr = nil
my_array.each |item|
  do_something_with(item) if prev_attr and prev_attr == item.attribute
  prev_attr = item.attribute
end
```