# Check whether LinkedList is an SubList

Tags: java

```
public class CharNode {
    private char _data;
    private CharNode _next;
    public CharNode(char dat, CharNode n) {
        _data = dat;
        _next = n;
    }
    public char getData() {
       return _data;
    }
    public CharNode getNext() {
        return _next;
    }
    public void setData(char d) {
       _data = d;
    }
    public void setNext(CharNode node) {
       _next = node;
     }
}

public class CharList {
    private CharNode _head;
    public CharList( ) {
        _head = null;
    }
    public CharList (CharNode node) {
        _head = node;
    }

    public int subList(IntList list)
    {
        int count = 0;
        IntNode listNode = _head;
        IntNode otherListNode = list._head; ;

        while (listNode != null)
        {
            if (otherListNode == null)
                otherListNode = list._head;
            if (listNode.getValue() == otherListNode.getValue())
            {
                listNode = listNode.getNext();
                otherListNode = otherListNode.getNext();
                if (otherListNode == null)
                    count++;
            }
            else
            {
                listNode = listNode.getNext();
                otherListNode = list._head;
            }              
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

I need to write function `public int subList (CharList list)` that gets `list` and returns how many times this list exist. 
For example if my list is `a b c d a b g e` and the list received as parameter is `a b` it will return 2.
**The method should be as efficient as possible.**

Currently my problem is that I don't know how to loop over the two lists at the same time in order to compare the values

Comment: Which part are you having problem with? Finding any sublist? Counting sublists? Making it efficient?

Comment: if the elements are `char`, why dont you just use strings and basic string methods? ie. search 'ab' inside 'aaaabcca'

Comment: We are not doing it all for you. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't know hot loop over the two lists at the same time in order to compare the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over the two lists at the same time:

```
public bool equalsSubList(CharNode other) {
  CharNode node1 = this;  
  CharNode node2 = other;  
  while (node1 != null && node2 != null) { 
    // compare data from both nodes
    node1 = node1.getNext();
    node2 = node2.getNext();
  }
  // return true if all nodes where compared and are equal
}
```

For the complete solution, you will have to loop over your list once, and the other list as many times as there are matches. Let's take your example, `a b c d a b g e` compared to `a b`:

```
other |   this
      |
a b   |   a b c d a b g e 
^     |   ^ (match a, go to next in both lists)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e   |
  ^   |     ^ (match a b, counter is 1, go to next this, restart other)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
^     |       ^ (does not match a, go to next this, restart other)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
^     |         ^ (does not match a, go to next this, restart other)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
^     |           ^ (match a, go to next in both lists)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
  ^   |             ^ (match a b, counter is 2, go to next this, restart other)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
^     |               ^ (does not match a, go to next this, restart other)
a b   |   a b c d a b g e
^     |                 ^ (does not match a, go to next this, restart other)
```

Comment: thanks, in this case i will loop over list again and again, how can i loop over my list only once ? (O(n))

Comment: Shouldn't it be `CharNode`, `CharList` and `getData()` instead of `IntNode`, `IntList` and `getValue()`? To check if your solution is good try debuging it with different test scenarios and compare the program with the desired behavior. Make sure you create unit tests to do this!

Comment: Thanks, BTW my solution is O(n) ?

Comment: Yes, if you follow the behavior above, it will be O(n). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909307/what-does-on-mean