# Given an unsorted linked list, find the element with the largest value. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, syntax, linked-list

I'm new to coding and learning Linked List problems. I found a solution but don't really understand what they do.
what does (!node.next) mean? Is it the same as node.next != null?

Also, I don't understand this line
return (node.value > biggestValueInRest ? node.value
: biggestValueInRest);

Does it mean that if node.value is greater than biggestValueInRest, then node.value = biggestValueInRest?

Here is the solution

```
function findMax(node) {
  if (!node.next) {
    return node.value;
  } else {
    const biggestValueInRest = findMax(node.next);

    return (node.value > biggestValueInRest ? node.value
      : biggestValueInRest);
  }
}
```

Comment: `!node.next` checks for any falsy value, it returns `true` if it's `null`, `false` or any other [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

Comment: *"Does it mean that if node.value is greater than biggestValueInRest, then node.value = biggestValueInRest?"* kind of, it returns the value (so it indeed sets `biggestValueInRest` thanks to the recursive return) rather than setting `node.value`, it's a [ternary expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Answer (score 0):

> what does (!node.next) mean? Is it the same as node.next != null?

The `!` is the negation operator, it negates the value placed in front of it.

for example `!node.next` is the same as `node.next == false`.

In this case, `!node.next` will return `true` if `node.next` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) like `false` or `null` or `undefined`.

In the `if` statement of your code, it will return the current node's value if there's no next node linked to that node since, in linked lists, nodes contain a value and a link to the next node.

> Also, I don't understand this line return (node.value > biggestValueInRest ? node.value : biggestValueInRest);

> Does it mean that if node.value is greater than biggestValueInRest, then node.value = biggestValueInRest?

That's a ternary operator, it's like a shortened `if` that returns a value.

`return (node.value > biggestValueInRest ? node.value : biggestValueInRest);`

would be the same as:

```
if (node.value > biggestValueInRest)
  return node.value;
else
  return biggestValueInRest;
```

The syntax of the ternary operator is basically:

`"condition" ? "value to return if true" : "value to return if false"`

And to fully answer your question.

> I found a solution but don't really understand what they do.

The solution provided is a [recursive](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-functions/) one, it will call itself for each node in the linked lists until it reaches the final one ( the one which's `node.next` is empty ), and once that's done, it will return the biggest value of each comparison from there.

Recursive functions aren't always a good practice, since their [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) can escalate depending on how the developer implemented it.

In this case, it would be [O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1909374/11269158) which means that it's linear, which is not too bad for a recursive function.

This means that the time the function will take to finish is affected in proportion to the number of items `n` the linked list has.

So if it takes 1s per node, then 100 nodes would be 100s for the function to finish.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been simpler in python but what you can do is create a function that is looks something like this, will explain later

> assuming the list consist only of numeric values

```
Function(ListItems) {
 Let biggest_val = 0;

 For (let i = 0; i < ListItems.length; i++) {
   If (LisItems[i] > biggest_val) {
  biggest_val = ListItems[i]
}
 }
}
```

We are first initialising a variable to hold the biggest value of the list for us, and then creating a for loop to loop through the list and check if the current value is greater than our current biggest value if so update the value of our biggest val.

> the node.value > biggestValueInRest ? node.value  : biggestValueInRest is called a [turnary operator][1] it is a short hand if statement but since you're just beginning it is better to stick with the traditional one

[1] : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator