# Paths in undirected graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

We are given an undirected graph G = (V, E) and two vertices s, t ∈ V . We consider simple
paths between s and t. A path is simple if every vertex is visited at most once.

<del>Are the following in P or NP-complete?</del>

Does an efficient algorithm polynomial time exist for the following?

"n" represents the number of vertices in the graph "V"

1. Is there a simple path from s to t of length at most n/100?
2. Is there a simple path from s to t of length at least n/100?
3. Is there a simple path from s to t of length exactly n/100?
4. Are there two edge-disjoint paths from s to t? (Two paths are said to be edge- disjoint if they do not share an edge.)

My thoughts (please correct me if I'm wrong) Your input is appreciated.

1. I think I can run Dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest path between S and T in polynomial time. So question 1 is in P.
2. I think it is necessary to enumerate all the simple paths from s to t. I don't know what the running time of this would be, but I think it would be worse than polynomial.
3. Similar to 2 above. No polynomial algorithm.
4. I'm not sure. I don't know of any efficient (poly-time algorithm) to find multiple paths between two nodes but that doesn't mean that they don't exist.

Comment: "n" represents the number of vertices in the graph V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track.  I wrote [another piece on NP-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308213/explaining-computational-complexity-theory#309507) to which I'm going to refer you for some of the details, but recall that basically you need to do two things to prove something NP-complete:

1. Show the problem is in NP
2. Show a polynomial time reduction to
   a problem already known to be
   NP-complete.

Doing 1 is pretty easy (if something walking the graph "knew" all the right decision of the next edge to take, would it find an answer in polynomial time?); I'd think seriously about the "decision TSP" problem I describe in the other note.

Comment: I'm allowed to assume that if all the problems are either P or NP-complete. So if I can't think of a polytime algorithm then I can assume that the problem is NP-complete. You are correct but I am hoping to avoid a reduction if possible.

Answer (score 0):

What I've come up with:

1. Same as you said, use any applicable SPP algorithm.
2. This is the longest path decision problem, which is NP-Hard even for unweighted graphs.
3. For unweighted graphs, a linear number of applications would suffice to solve 2, so it is NP-Hard as well.
4. You can use maximum flow algorithms with unit capacity to find the maximum number of edge-disjoint paths.