# What is O(log* N)?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, logarithm, iterated-logarithm

What is O(log* N) and how is it different from O(log N)?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly No answer on `O(log* N)` unfortunately.

Comment: Is this question about the * after log or about O() notation in general?

Comment: It's in some advanced data structures, though I'm out of school for too long to recall where it comes from!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111426/did-you-apply-computational-complexity-theory-in-real-life and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107165/big-o-for-eight-year-olds covers this question

Comment: I guess not so advanced, just remembered - Union Find with path compression's initial lower bound was set at O(n log* n) until it was lowered to O(A n), where A is the inverse Ackermann function..

Comment: Heh.  In practice, I think that I would be satisfied with an estimate of O(n) for that.  :-)

Comment: This video is quite nice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2vprYeJ0qs . It demonstrates that `lg*` follows exactly the same pattern like the normal functions `lg`, `division`, so it is not an artificial function even if it looks so.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

`O( log* N )` is "[iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm)":

> In computer science, the iterated logarithm of n, written log* n (usually read "log star"), is the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to 1.

Comment: That is really interesting thing I'd not heard of. Q+A +1 each. I guess O(log*N) is for-all-intents-and-purposes O(1). Cool.

Comment: @greg, no log(n) means that as the number of elements goes up the time more slowly. eg. 10x as many elements only makes the function take 2x as long

Comment: I think I first came across it in the analysis of the Union-Find algorithm, when it was `O( N log* N )` before it was improved to `O( A N )`, where A is the inverse Ackermann function.  I still don't understand the latter proof, but the `O( N log* N )` algorithm is a relatively good read.

Comment: @Martin, but this is log*(n) which goes up crazily slowly, such that log*(2^65536 -1) = 5. You might as well call that constant.

Comment: Sorry hadn't appreciated the log-star difference, thanks - learning something new!

Comment: @MartinBeckett If you want, take `log*(x)=10`, or `2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2^2`, this is a number that if all the universe were full of electrons, I'm sure their number won't reach half of this number. Constant? mathematically, not, but practically, yes.

Answer (score 34):

The `log* N` bit is an iterated algorithm which grows very slowly, much slower than just `log N`. You basically just keep iteratively 'logging' the answer until it gets below one (E.g: `log(log(log(...log(N)))`), and the number of times you had to `log()` is the answer.

Anyway, this is a five-year old question on Stackoverflow, but no code?(!) Let's fix that - here's implementations for both the recursive and iterative functions (they both give the same result):

```
public double iteratedLogRecursive(double n, double b)
{
    if (n > 1.0) {
        return 1.0 + iteratedLogRecursive( Math.Log(n, b),b );
    }
    else return 0;
}

public int iteratedLogIterative(double n, double b)
{
    int count=0;
    while (n >= 1) {
        n = Math.Log(n,b);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

log* (n)- **"log Star n"** as known as **"Iterated logarithm"**

In simple word you can assume log*(n) = log(log(log(.....(log(n))))

log*(n) is very powerful.

**Example:**

**1)** Log* (n)=5 where n= Number of atom in universe

**2)** Tree Coloring using 3 colors can be done in log*(n) while coloring a Tree 2 colors are enough but complexity will be O(n) then.

**3)** Finding the Delaunay triangulation of a set of points knowing the Euclidean minimum spanning tree: randomized O(n log* n) time.