# What does "log*" mean?

Tags: big-o, iterated-logarithm

I have come across the term `O(log* N)` in a book I'm reading on data structures.  What does `log*` mean?  I cannot [find it on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=log+*), and WolframAlpha [doesn't understand it either](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=O%28log*+N%29).

Comment: "I cannot find it on Google". Googling for 'log star' works fine.

Comment: try "iterated logarithm of x from 0 to 6" or "IteratedLog(4)" in WolframAlpha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is O(log\* N)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387656/what-is-olog-n)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's iterated logarithm. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) for a description of lots of different time complexities,  and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) for more details on the iterated logarithm itself.

The iterated logarithm is the number of times the logarithm has to be applied before the result becomes one or less.

Answer (score 27):

It's called [iterated logarithm function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm). It is a very slowly growing function. For example:

- `lg*(2) = 1`
- `lg*(4) = 2`
- `lg*(16) = 3`
- `lg*(65536) = 4`
- `lg*(2^65536) = 5` /note that (2^65536) is much larger than the number of atoms in the observable universe/

Or in the case of Big O it could pretty much be considered as constant time.

Comment: More succinctly, the iterated logarithm counts the number of times you would have to take the logarithm to reduce a number to 1.

Comment: So the inverse would be iterated exponentiation, which is the next in the sequence: addition, multiplication (=iterated addition), exponentiation (=iterated multiplication), ...

Answer (score 5):

log* (n)- "log Star n" as known as "Iterated logarithm"

In simple word you can assume log* (n)= log(log(log(.....(log* (n))))

log* (n) is very powerful.

Example:

1) Log* (n)=5 where n= Number of atom in universe

2) Tree Coloring using 3 colors can be done in log*(n) while coloring Tree 2 colors are enough but complexity will be O(n) then.

3) Finding the Delaunay triangulation of a set of points knowing the Euclidean minimum spanning tree: randomized O(n log* n) time.

I hope you can Visualize **Log* (n)** like this on WolframAlpha [Check here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%20log%28%20log%28%20log%20%28n%29%29%29)

Answer (score 2):

log* is the number of times you need to apply the log-function until you reach a value which less or equal to 1. For Instance: log*(16) = 3, because log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(log<sub>2</sub>(16))) = 1.

For practical purposes you can treat it like a constant, because this function grows very slow.