# Finding Big Theta

Tags: algorithm, notation, recurrence

I am in a Data Structures and Algorithms class. I am trying to indicate if f(n) is Big Theta of g(n). I will also have to indicate Big O, small o, etc... but I am lost about the way to approach this particular pair.

```
f(n) = log* (log n)
g(n) = log( log* n )
```

From what I have currently learned, if this pair completes this statement

```
Θ(g(n))={f(n):there exists c_1, c_2 > 0 and n_0 <br>
 such that 0 ≤ c_1 g(n) ≤ f(n) ≤ c_2 g(n) for all n ≥ n_0}.
```

My problem is that I have no idea what `log *` is and how to use it.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question. Ask this on the Math site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have no idea what log * is

Well, look it up. Unfortunately, Google doesn't search for symbols too well, but Googling `log star` turns up the [iterated logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_logarithm) immediately, and [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/), a search engine that doesn't ignore symbols, turns up a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387656/what-is-olog-n) explaining it. It's also probably in your book or course notes somewhere.

The iterated logarithm, denoted `log*(n)`, is the number of times you need to take the logarithm of `n` before you get a value less than or equal to 1.

To solve the problem, consider the following. If you need to take the logarithm of `n` `log*(n)` times before you get a value <= 1, how many times do you need to take the logarithm of `log(n)` to do the same thing?

Comment: So... to indicate whether f(n) is Big Theta of g(n). Would the algebra in solving it be the same as any other log base x problem?

Comment: @user3339453: Not quite the same, but pretty similar. Note that `log*` isn't a logarithm, so you can't apply the usual equalities for logarithms to it.