# what does log* (log n) mean,what will it represent

Tags: performance, time-complexity, logarithm, natural-logarithm

what does log* (log n) mean? what does the * represent? what is its expansion to compare with other logarithmic function like log(log n)??which one is greater among log* (log n) and (log(log n)^log n)

My approach to solve which one is better:
applied log on both sides,but do not know what log(log* (log n)) will be

Comment: What language is this question about?

Comment: I want to use the  log* (log n) function in logarithmic analysis.this does comes under logarithms

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is O(log\* N)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387656/what-is-olog-n)